# I just installed DotNetNuke

Tags: content-management-system, dotnetnuke

I just installed DotNetNuke expecting to have a CMS like the ones many people generally use, Wordpress, among others, but now I can't find what to do. It shows me a screen with options that take me to other places.

Can someone please tell me what to do to have a CMS with the DotNetNuke that I have installed, or if that platform is to create the CMS somewhere else, which is not what I wanted to do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of videos and documentation about DNN. Examples:

- [DNN Docs](https://docs.dnncommunity.org/)
- [DNN Tutorial for Beginners Part 1 - Learn how to install DNN](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dhsczjjgkmg)
- [How To Videos](https://dnncommunity.org/Resources/Videos#)

Just use Google... and the [DNN Community Website](https://dnncommunity.org) to ask questions in the forum, read the blogs, see the tutorials etc. The community is always helpful.